# Portable Directory Path Variables Real-time List

Tags: directory, resource-urls

Wordpress: 5.0.3

CiviCRM: Upgraded from 4.7x to 5.9.0

Everything is working, but now I'm getting these status notices about portable path variables. From my status page:

> To maximize portability, consider using a variable in each directory
>   (eg "[cms.root]" or "[civicrm.files]").

It would be great if a list of existing path variables and what they currently point to were actually made available on the "Directory Paths" and "Resource URLs" admin pages. Anything I can do to reduce possible mistakes makes me less anxious about updating my existing paths to the new preferred method.

Sort of Like this:

> **List of available path variables with their current real-time paths:**
>
> [cms.root] --> /home/myusername/mysite.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/
>
> [civicrm.files] --> /home/myusername/mysite.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/uploads/files/
>
> [cms.other.path] --> /home/myusername/mysite.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/whatever/
>
> Also tips on whether to add a slash when using something like:
>
> *Example temp file location: [cms.root]uploads/temp/*

Is this in the works?

Cheers in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you click the help icon in the help text at the top of the page, it shows you the current values.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This has opened another can of worms, so I've opened a separate SE CiviCRM question. I wonder if there is a minor bug.

Answer (score 1):

Can you make sure in Directories and Resource url settings you are using real-time paths rather hardcoded paths in all text fields on the form. eg [cms.root]uploads/temp/ and not using /home/myusername/mysite.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/

Some organisation define this settings in civicrm.settings.php if thats the case in yours than you will need to update your civicrm.settings.php file.

> **Note:** After doing the change make sure everything is working fine specially cron job and online signup/registration forms.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Thanks for you reply! Regardless of how the variables are achieved (default or in a settings file), if they're simply listed with their current (real-time) values somewhere in the admin page where they're needed, fewer mistakes will be made, right?

Also, variables that are derived from a settings file could be noted as such.

Comment: Yes, And it will be less pain to update these paths when site is moved or migrated to different path/server as [cms.root] etc will be derived from your apache and civicrm.settings file.